# Rails active admin filter for multiple words search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, search-multiple-words

I have a model called Post in my application with a title and content attributes. In the Activeadmin index page of this resource, I would like to perform a multiple word search for the content of the posts. By default (or by using filter :content, :as => :string), the filter on content only search for a word or an expression, but not for words that could be spread in the content of the post.

How can I perform a multiple word search filter with ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build completely custom filter as described https://gist.github.com/dmitry/4240801

I would definitely like to hear more how to make it simpler.